# How to implement geocoder with @react-native-mapbox-gl/maps library in react native

Tags: android, react-native, mapbox, mapbox-android, geocoder

i'm trying to implement Geocoder with the [@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps](https://github.com/react-native-mapbox-gl/maps) library as it's the sugestion in the official [Mapbox's website](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/maps-sdk-for-react-native/) for react native apps.

My map is fully operational, but when comes to Geocoder I couldn't find a proper library. Tried some react libraries but I got some errors and don't know where to go.
I've tried a lot already and couldn't get it to work.
Already tested the libraries [react-mapbox-gl-geocoder](https://github.com/groinder/react-mapbox-gl-geocoder), [@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder) and react-mui-mapbox-geocoder (can't post more then 8 links so just remove the space: www.npmjs.com /package/react-mui-mapbox-geocoder).
Even tried [react-map-gl-geocoder](https://github.com/SamSamskies/react-map-gl-geocoder) with [react-map-gl](https://github.com/visgl/react-map-gl) library that is deprecated to see if would work, as I've seen some examples with geocoder, but that didn't work as well.

Here's my code without the Geocoder libraries:

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import { 
  View, 
  Text, 
  StyleSheet, 
  PermissionsAndroid,
  TextInput,
  Keyboard,
} from 'react-native';
import Geolocation from "@react-native-community/geolocation";
import MapboxGL from '@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps';
import Colors from '../../styles/colors';

// Variáveis
granted = 1;

MapboxGL.setAccessToken('Mapbox token');
MapboxGL.setConnected(true);

async function requestLocationPermission() {
    try {
        granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
            PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            {
                title: 'App',
                message:
                'Necessita de permissão da sua localização para mostrar o mapa.',
                buttonNeutral: 'Perguntar mais tarde',
                buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
                buttonPositive: 'OK',
            },
        );
    } catch (err) {
        console.warn(err);
    }
}

export default function Home({ navigation }) {

    const permissaoLocalizacao = requestLocationPermission()

    const [position, setPosition] = useState({
        latitude: 0,
        longitude: 0
    });
    const [error, setError] = useState("");

    const getPosition = () => {
        Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        pos => {
            setError("");
            setPosition({
            latitude: pos.coords.latitude,
            longitude: pos.coords.longitude
            });
        },
        e => setError(e.message)
        );
    };

    const onMapPress = (event) => {

    }

    if (permissaoLocalizacao) {

        if (!position.longitude) {
            getPosition();
        }

        if (error) {
            console.log("error")
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                {/* alert('Sair do aplicativo'); */}
                </View>
            )
        }

        return (
        <View style={styles.container}>

            <MapboxGL.MapView
                style={styles.map}
                onPress={onMapPress}
            >
                <MapboxGL.Camera
                    zoomLevel={16}
                    centerCoordinate={[position.longitude, position.latitude]}
                />

                <MapboxGL.PointAnnotation
                    id="PosicaoAtual"
                    coordinate={[position.longitude, position.latitude]}
                >
                    <View style={styles.annotationContainer}>
                    <View style={styles.annotationFill} />
                    </View>
                </MapboxGL.PointAnnotation>

            </MapboxGL.MapView>

        </View>
        );
    }else{
        return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>Necessário permissão da localização</Text>
        </View>
        );
    }

}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  },
  map: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  annotationContainer: {
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 15,
  },
  annotationFill: {
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
    borderRadius: 15,
    backgroundColor: Colors.primary,
    transform: [{ scale: 0.8 }],
  }
});
```

And this is my package.json, it's a little polluted, cause I've tried so many things already:

```
{
  "name": "mapbox",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder": "^4.5.1",
    "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^2.0.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.6",
    "@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps": "^7.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.4.2",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.5.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.0.6",
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-map-gl": "^5.2.5",
    "react-map-gl-geocoder": "^2.0.11",
    "react-mapbox-gl-geocoder": "^1.1.0",
    "react-mui-mapbox-geocoder": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native": "0.62.2",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.0.0-beta.10",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.1.1",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.6",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.9.6",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^1.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.0.1",
    "eslint": "^7.0.0",
    "jest": "^26.0.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.11.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

My android/build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2")

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

My android/setting.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'mapbox'

// MapBox
include ':@react-native-mapbox-gl_maps'
project(':@react-native-mapbox-gl_maps').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps/android/rctmgl')

// Vector Icons
include ':react-native-vector-icons'
project(':react-native-vector-icons').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android')

apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
include ':app'
```

My android/app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation. If none specified and
 *   // "index.android.js" exists, it will be used. Otherwise "index.js" is
 *   // default. Can be overridden with ENTRY_FILE environment variable.
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance#enable-the-ram-format
 *   bundleCommand: "ram-bundle",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

/**
 * Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
 *
 * This should be set on project.ext.react and mirrored here.  If it is not set
 * on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
 * and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
 */
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mapbox"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst "lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so"
        pickFirst "lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so"
        pickFirst "lib/x86/libc++_shared.so"
        pickFirst "lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so"
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"

    // React native screens
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0-alpha02'

    // MapBox
    implementation project(':@react-native-mapbox-gl_maps')

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
      exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    // Vector Icons
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)

// Vector Icons
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
```

And the MainApplication;

```
package com.mapbox;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import com.mapbox.rctmgl.RCTMGLPackage; // Mapbox
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;  // Vector Icons
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
      new ReactNativeHost(this) {
        @Override
        public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
          return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
          // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());

          //new VectorIconsPackage()  // Vector Icons

          return packages;
        }

        @Override
        protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
          return "index";
        }
      };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
    initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
  }

  /**
   * Loads Flipper in React Native templates. Call this in the onCreate method with something like
   * initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
   *
   * @param context
   * @param reactInstanceManager
   */
  private static void initializeFlipper(
      Context context, ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      try {
        /*
         We use reflection here to pick up the class that initializes Flipper,
        since Flipper library is not available in release mode
        */
        Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("com.mapbox.ReactNativeFlipper");
        aClass
            .getMethod("initializeFlipper", Context.class, ReactInstanceManager.class)
            .invoke(null, context, reactInstanceManager);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**I don't know if this react libraries could work, but this are the errors that I'm facing:**

-I replaced the project directory with  to be more clean

**-> Importing react-mapbox-gl-geocoder:**

-It first occurred the missing of 'events' and 'http' libraries, then I added them and couldn't resolve this one.

```
error: Error: While trying to resolve module `http` from file `<projectfolder>\node_modules\react-mapbox-gl-geocoder\dist\index.js`, the package `<projectfolder>\node_modules\http\package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`<projectfolder>\node_modules\http\index`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

  * <projectfolder>\node_modules\http\index(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  * <projectfolder>\node_modules\http\index\index(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (<projectfolder>\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:65:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (<projectfolder>\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:287:16)
    at Object.resolve (<projectfolder>\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:267:42)
    at <projectfolder>\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:434:31
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (<projectfolder>\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:431:18)
    at <projectfolder>\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:275:33
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (<projectfolder>\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:87:24)
    at _next (<projectfolder>\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:107:9)
```

**-> Importing @mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder:**

This occures in build:

```
[Sat May 23 2020 21:41:54.544]  WARN     Require cycle: node_modules\@react-native-mapbox-gl\maps\javascript\index.js -> node_modules\@react-native-mapbox-gl\maps\javascript\components\annotations\Annotation.js -> node_modules\@react-native-mapbox-gl\maps\javascript\index.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
```

And this in the app:

[app error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZJjY.png)

So I added the 'expo-random' and 'nonoid' libraries, but then it ask's me for '@unimodules/core', and then '@unimodules/react-native-adapter' and another error, so I stopped.

**-> Importing react-mui-mapbox-geocoder**

Gives me an arror to update Autosuggest library.

**-> Importing react-map-gl-geocoder with map-gl**

This occures in build:

```
[Sat May 23 2020 16:54:57.817]  WARN     Require cycle: node_modules\viewport-mercator-project\dist\es5\web-mercator-viewport.js -> node_modules\viewport-mercator-project\dist\es5\fit-bounds.js -> node_modules\viewport-mercator-project\dist\es5\web-mercator-viewport.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
```

And this in the app.
[app error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFcZG.png)

If you see something else wrong or that could be better, please let me know. I'm still learning react native and I may have misunderstood something.
Hope we can find a solution and that this helps others to.